# Why won't dplyr's top_n() work?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe called `df`:

```
City,State,Price,Dogs
Portland,OR,75,1
Portland,OR,100,3
San Diego,CA,12,4
San Diego,CA,23,5
...
```

I used `dplyr`'s `summarise` and `group_by` functions...

```
df.median <- summarise(
  group_by(
    df, 
    State, 
    City
  ),
  MEDIAN_PRICE = median(Price),
  SUM_DOGS = sum(Dogs)
)
```

But when I run `top_n(df.median, 100, SUM_DOGS)`, R does not give me cities with the 100 highest values in `SUM_DOGS`. It just returns `df.median`.

Why?

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: @MekkiMacAulay Edited answer

Comment: If you don't want the top 100 values per `State`, you likely need to `ungroup`.

Comment: @aosmith If I want the top 100 from `df.median`, how do I use `ungroup` to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You likely need to `ungroup`, so you pick the `top_n` from the whole dataset rather than the `top_n` from each State (as your dataset is currently grouped).

```
top_n(ungroup(df.median), 100, SUM_DOGS)
```