# top_n() returning all the rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Below is the head of my `tibble`. I am trying to find the top two countries with the highest `r.squared` using `top_n()` command. Why is that I am getting back the whole `dataframe` instead of just 2 rows? Appreciate inputs.

```
head(model_p)

country
<fctr>
r.squared
<dbl>
Algeria 0.9522064   
Argentina   0.9843108   
Australia   0.9830777   
Austria 0.9866741   
Bangladesh  0.9485248   
Belgium 0.9902805   

dim(model_p)
[1] 77  2

model_p %>% top_n(n=2, wt=r.squared)

country
<fctr>
r.squared
<dbl>
Algeria 0.952206405
Argentina   0.984310769
Australia   0.983077726
Austria 0.986674082
Bangladesh  0.948524805
Belgium 0.990280511
Benin   0.963144992
Bolivia 0.992357210
Botswana    0.013649835
Brazil  0.994024334
...
1-10 of 77 rows
```

Comment: Please provide some data in the form of `dput(head(x))`, it makes it easier to review your question and post answers.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36341295/why-wont-dplyrs-top-n-work

Comment: The OP has not grouped is his data - at least this is not something that appears from his scarce provision of codes. Therefore the link, is not useful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and advise from others, I understood the problem. Earlier, at some point, my dataframe was grouped. I understand that it is a good practice to ungroup the dataframe, if it s being used for further later analysis. So, piping my dataframe through ungroup() worked fine.

```
model_p <- model_p %>% ungroup()
model_p %>% top_n(wt=r.squared, n=2)
```

Given dplyr strategy to supersede top_n() with slice_*() function, the two lines can be:

```
model_p <- model_p %>% ungroup()
model_p %>% slice_max(order_by=r.squared, n=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `R Documentation` of `Tidyverse`, it is immediately clear that `top_n()` is superseded by `slice_*`. This should work for you,

```
mtcars %>%
    slice_max(order_by = mpg, n = 2)
```

Where `order_by = mpg`, orders the data according to `mpg`.

**Edit:**

After reviewing your question, I just realized that you are trying to sort according to a `factor`. Convert these to `numeric`, and you will be able to get top N.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried suggested slice_max change. Initially it gave lots of package compatibility issues. I have updated my R, RStudio, tidyverse (including dplyr) to all latest versions. Thereafter slice_max started working, the result is same. Instead of getting top 2 rows, I am getting full tibble. Also, please note that the sort is on r.squared, which is not a factor and does not need conversion to numeric.

Comment: Please read my answer again. You are working with ‘factors’ not ‘numerics’